# why is my texture repeating after UV unwrapping

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image]

after doing node editing and UV unwrapping my texture logo is repeating.i just want a single logo.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The default when you make an image texture node is "Repeat":

[image]

[image]

If you set it to "Clip" instead it should only show your texture once

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worth noting that this does work, but that the texture and material view will still show the repeating of the texture, while using rendered view will show the correct  mapping of clip.